# Getting error 'git pull ...') before pushing again

Tags: github

I am very new to Github. I cloned a repo and created a `test` branch. After that I pushed the `test` branch and created a pull request. After that, I made the changes in `test` branch and committed the changes.

Before pushing my latest commit in `test`, I did the following in `test` branch:

```
git fetch
```

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

Now, I am trying to run the following command from the `test` command:

```
git push origin test
```

I am getting the following error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have already done `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/develop`. What should I do now? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do a git pull from instead git fetch. refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: Do I need to git pull in my `test` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebase, you're rewriting your history (and essentially putting commits from both branches in order) - if you have new commits on your branch this will generally put them in a different chain than they were in before.

This means git will think your branches are out of whack, but if you know that you had the latest before you started, you can force push.  This is generally OK when working on a branch by yourself.

If you are working off a shared branch where commits may be coming in regularly, I wouldn't do a `rebase` but would do regular `merge`s from the other branch instead.  This puts all the new stuff at the tip of your branch but avoids any history rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
You have to take pull first.

git pull origin test

After that u can push your data.
git push origin test

Answer (score -1):

Try This : You can do this **git pull** shortly after, The screen will appear. There are will be three cards. You can edit card,  it according to your own code from.

Before getting the error, you should do definitely **git pull**. don't forget :)